Land possession by the children of Abraham
According to the promise made by God to Abraham, these lands are ceded to his children.
Approximate Boundaries of the Promised Land
Southwest (Wadi of Egypt): Near the northeastern part of the Sinai Peninsula, close to the Wadi El-Arish, around 31.2° N, 33.8° E.
Southeast (Desert): The Negev Desert in southern Israel, around 30.5° N, 34.8° E.
Northeast (Euphrates River): Extending towards the Euphrates River, which runs through modern-day Syria and Iraq, around 35.0° N, 39.0° E.
Northwest (Lebanon): Near the southern border of modern Lebanon, close to the city of Tyre, around 33.3° N, 35.2° E.
West (Mediterranean Sea): Along the coast of the Mediterranean Sea, near Israel's coastline, around 32.0° N, 34.8° E.
The total land is approximately 400,000 KM2. Since it is over 4000 years since this promise was made, is it safe to conclude the people living in these lands today are all descendants of Abraham?

"is it safe to conclude the people living in these lands today are all descendants of Abraham?" — Making assumptions is seldom a good idea. Are you aware that Arabs are also children of Abraham?

@ Ray Butterworth - The astute and well-researched questioner does not seem to be "assuming" anything! He is asking for a conclusion based on rational deductions concerning real geographical dimensions. And those who have a thorough grasp on the history on the Bible have done him a service in their erudite answers!

@ ken4ward - For a quick answer consider the Samaritan region dealt with in the New Testament, and their nationality. (A mixture of races with non-Jewish blood.

No, it is not safe to say the people living on those lands are Abraham's descendants.
The promised land was conditional upon their keeping YHVH's commandments, and as they repeatedly fell into idolatry, which as His wife He considered them guilty of adultery, YHVH gave them a bill of divorcement centuries ago.

58 `If thou dost not observe to do all the words of this law which are written in this book, to fear this honoured and fearful name -- Jehovah thy God --


59 then hath Jehovah made wonderful thy strokes, and the strokes of thy seed -- great strokes, and stedfast, and evil sicknesses, and stedfast.


60 `And He hath brought back on thee all the diseases of Egypt, of the presence of which thou hast been afraid, and they have cleaved to thee;


61 also every sickness and every stroke which is not written in the book of this law; Jehovah doth cause them to go up upon thee till thou art destroyed,


62 and ye have been left with few men, instead of which ye have been as stars of the heavens for multitude, because thou hast not hearkened to the voice of Jehovah thy God.


63 `And it hath been, as Jehovah hath rejoiced over you to do you good, and to multiply you, so doth Jehovah rejoice over you to destroy you, and to lay you waste; and ye have been pulled away from off the ground whither thou art going in to possess it;


64 and Jehovah hath scattered thee among all the peoples, from the end of the earth even unto the end of the earth; and thou hast served there other gods which thou hast not known, thou and thy fathers -- wood and stone.


65 `And among those nations thou dost not rest, yea, there is no resting-place for the sole of thy foot, and Jehovah hath given to thee there a trembling heart, and failing of eyes, and grief of soul;  (Deu. 28:58-65, YLT)


26 and they go and serve other gods, and bow themselves to them -- gods which they have not known, and which He hath not apportioned to them;


27 and the anger of Jehovah burneth against that land, to bring in on it all the reviling that is written in this book,


28 and Jehovah doth pluck them from off their ground in anger, and in fury, and in great wrath, and doth cast them unto another land, as [at] this day. (Deu. 29:26-28, YLT)

And,...

6 And Jehovah saith unto me, in the days of Josiah the king, `Hast thou seen that which backsliding Israel hath done? She is going on every high mountain, and unto the place of every green tree, and committeth fornication there.


7 And I say, after her doing all these, Unto Me thou dost turn back, and she hath not turned back, and see [it] doth her treacherous sister Judah.


8 And I see when (for all the causes whereby backsliding Israel committed adultery) I have sent her away, and I give the bill of her divorce unto her, that treacherous Judah her sister hath not feared, and goeth and committeth fornication -- she also.  (Jer. 3:6-8, YLT)

See also Isa. 50:1 and Ezek. 36:17-19. That land promise was fulfilled in everyway (Josh. 21:45).  It was the disobedience of the Israelite that caused that land to be polluted with their idolatry and their sins against YHVH, and the promise was negated.
Judah was brought back out of the Babylonian captivity for one reason - to bring in the promised Messiah.

The sceptre turneth not aside from Judah, And a lawgiver from between his feet, Till his Seed come; And his [is] the obedience of peoples. (Gen. 49:10, YLT)


5 Lo, days are coming -- an affirmation of Jehovah, And I have raised to David a righteous shoot, And a king hath reigned and acted wisely, And done judgment and righteousness in the earth.  6 In his days is Judah saved, and Israel dwelleth confidently, And this his name that Jehovah proclaimeth him, `Our Righteousness.' (Jer. 23:5-6, YLT)


31 Lo, days are coming, an affirmation of Jehovah, And I have made with the house of Israel And with the house of Judah a new covenant, 32 Not like the covenant that I made with their fathers, In the day of My laying hold on their hand, To bring them out of the land of Egypt, In that they made void My covenant, And I ruled over them -- an affirmation of Jehovah.


33 For this [is] the covenant that I make, With the house of Israel, after those days, An affirmation of Jehovah, I have given My law in their inward part, And on their heart I do write it, And I have been to them for God, And they are to me for a people. (Jer. 31:31-33, YLT)


24 and he said to them, `This is my blood of the new covenant, which for many is being poured out; (Mark 24:14, YLT)

The new covenant was not a land based, earthly kingdom promise.  The New Jerusalem is not an earthly city, but a spiritual city established by the blood of Christ.

14 how much more shall the blood of the Christ (who through the age-during Spirit did offer himself unblemished to God) purify your conscience from dead works to serve the living God?


15 And because of this, of a new covenant he is mediator, that, death having come, for redemption of the transgressions under the first covenant, those called may receive the promise of the age-during inheritance, (Heb. 9:14-15, YLT)

The age-during inheritance is not an earthly kingdom.  That old covenant land promise was for a purpose to show forth God's people as an example of how to be right with God.  That promise was always to bring forth the Messiah that did fulfill all of the old covenant law, and established the new covenant through His sacrifice so that ALL NATIONS could come to God through His Son, Yeshua (Jesus).
That old covenant land promise is no longer in force, as the plan of salvation has been established, the inheritance promised is an eternal life with our Father in heaven for all those of every nation on earth who will be immersed into Christ (Mark 16:16), be covered by His passover (1 Cor. 5:7) whereby we are clothed with His righteousness and our sins are forgiven.  Everyone of every nation who is baptized into Christ is now counted for the seed of Abraham and is the true Israel of God (Gal. 3:26-29).
That promise is not dependent upon a geographical land nation. That old covenant promised land was transformed into the new covenant promised land of the spiritual kingdom of God which is not of this world (John 18:36; Luke 17:21).
See my post The Promised Land: Between the Cross and the Kingdom.

4000 years, countless generations, each one potentially increasing the number of Abraham’s descendants exponentially. Safe to conclude? Short Answer: No.
For starters, the region has seen numerous migrations, conquests, and intermarriages over the millennia, which makes tracing lineage challenging if not nearly impossible.
Also, people move and mix. Over the centuries, there have been numerous migrations, invasions, and periods of trade in the region, each which would bring in new people and take others away. On a pure probability note, it is highly unlikely that all current inhabitants of the region are descendants of Abraham.
Secondly, the concept of being a “descendant of Abraham” according to scripture is not solely about biological lineage.
Christians are not strangers to the covenant. They are grafted in through faith in the Jewish Messiah.

Therefore it is of faith that it might be according to grace, so that
the promise might be sure to all the seed, not only to those who are
of the law, but also to those who are of the faith of Abraham, who is
the father of us all (Romans 4:16)


For if the Gentiles have been partakers of their spiritual things [Abrahamic Covenant blessings],
their duty is also to minister to them in material things. (Romans 15:27)

Romans even goes so far as saying:

But it is not that the word of God has taken no effect. For they are
not all Israel who are of Israel, 7 nor are they all children because
they are the seed of Abraham; but, “In Isaac your seed shall be
called.” 8 That is, those who are the children of the flesh, these are
not the children of God; but the children of the promise are counted
as the seed. (Romans 9:6-8)

Of course, it’s possible that many people living in these lands have some genetic connection to Abraham, it’s also likely that many do not. Conversely, there are probably descendants of Abraham living in many other parts of the world due to diaspora and migration.

The Abrahamic Covenant had a number of aspects - see the appendix 1 below.
The land component of the Abrahamic covenant was rather vague and defined simply as “from the wadi of Egypt to the great river Euphrates” (Gen 15:18).  It was only ever fulfilled during the time of King Solomon (1 Kings 4:20-25, 2 Chron 9:26).  However, because of Israel’s unfaithfulness, Isaiah prophesied that they would lose all the land (Isa 27:12), which finally happened when Babylon conquered them (2 Kings 24:7).  Israel has never regained all this territory.
However, parts of this land have always been occupied by Abraham's family since the Exodus from Egypt and remains so today.
Second, the people that constituted the people of "Israel" were far more than just Abraham's descendants.  see appendix 2 below.
APPENDIX 1 - Abrahamic Covenant
Gen 13:14-17, 15:1-17, 17:1-27, 18:9-15, 22:15-18
The Abrahamic Covenant is stated in three places, Gen 15 & 17, are 13 years apart (and repeated in Gen 12:1-3, 13:14-17, 18:9-15, 22:15-18 without using the word “covenant” nor formal sacrifices) and was an eternal covenant, Gen 13:15, 17:9, 13, 19.  The covenant consisted of the following:
Gen 15

God promises Abram a biological son
God promises Abram uncountable descendants
God promises Abram’s descendants the land of Canaan, “from the wadi of Egypt to the great river Euphrates”.
God promises to return Abram’s descendants to Canaan after Egyptian slavery of 400 years
God promises to punish the Egyptians
God promises great possessions to Abram’s descendants when they leave Egypt
The covenant was initiated and signified by a ceremony (significant to the culture of Abraham) of cutting several animals in half and God passing between the halves, and (and so solemnly promising) to keep the provisions of the covenant.

This ceremony of cutting sacrificed animals in half is a direct allusion of the word “berith” (= “covenant”), meaning, “to cut”.  That this covenant was a covenant of grace is confirmed by Gen 15:6, “Abram believed the LORD and he credited it to him as righteousness”.  (See also Rom 4:3, 22, Gal 3:6, James 2:23.)
Gen 17, 18:9-15

God promises a biological son by Sarah, viz. Isaac
God promises to greatly increase Abram’s numbers
God promises Abram that he would be the father of many nations
God promises Abraham the land of Canaan
God promises that Ishmael would also be fruitful
Abraham and his descendants must promise to be faithful to God
The covenant is signified by the token/sign (Heb: “oth”, Gen 17:10, 11, 13, Rom 4:11) of circumcision (= circular cut), Acts 7:8, and a change of name from Abram to Abraham.

It is immediately clear that this covenant is a re-statement, with only slight variations, of the covenant in Gen 15, and was an eternal covenant, Gen 17:7, 13.
APPENDIX 2 - People of "Israel"
The Old Testament contains many examples of foreigners becoming part of Israel, indicating that the Israelite Covenant was open to all and was never exclusive.  For example:

Abraham’s own household must have consisted of perhaps 2000 people just to be able to raise an army of 318 men to liberate Lot, Gen 14:14.  Indeed, Abraham’s chief servant (from Damascus) was clearly a believer and very devout as shown in Gen 24.
The unfortunate story in Gen 38 about Judah and Tamar shows that a foreigner became the mother of the tribe of Judah.
When Jacob entered Egypt, his family numbered 75 people (Acts 7:14, Ex 1:5).  Some of these were not direct descendants of Abraham such as the wives of the 12 patriarchs, notably Joseph’s own wife.  215 years and four generations later at the exodus, Israel’s army had over 600,000 men, excluding women and children, (Ex 12:37, Num 1:46, etc) suggesting a total population of several million people, requiring many additions.  This included a significant mixed multitude (Ex 12:38) showing that Israel obviously consisted of many non-biological Jews had joined.  (Note that it is biologically impossible for Israelite numbers to have grown from 75 to several million biologically without many outside additions.)
Moses married a Midianite (Ex 2:16-21) also known as a Cushite.  Miriam and Aaron were severely reprimanded and punished for displaying racism (Num 12:1, 2)
Caleb, who represented and led the tribe of Judah was a Kennizite (Num 32:12).
Rahab was a Canaanite (Josh 2:1, 2, Matt 1:5)
Ruth was Moabite (Ruth 1:4 16, 17, Matt 1:5) – these last two make King David descended from foreigners (Ruth 4:13-16).
Uriah was a Hittite (2 Sam 11:3)
King David’s elite personal regiment consisted of Gittites, that is, Philistines (2 Sam 15:18-22, 1 Chron 18:17)
Isa 14:1 - When the LORD has compassion on Jacob and again chooses Israel, and settles them on their own land, then strangers will join them and attach themselves to the house of Jacob.
Isa 56:6, 7 - And the foreigners who join themselves to the LORD to minister to Him, to love the name of the LORD, and to be His servants— all who keep the Sabbath without profaning it and who hold fast to My covenant—I will bring them to My holy mountain and make them joyful in My house of prayer.  Their burnt offerings and sacrifices will be accepted on My altar, for My house will be called a house of prayer for all the nations.”  See also V3.
The Rechabites were Kenites (Jer 35:1-19)
Many other foreigners lived in Israel (1 Chron 22:2, 17, 2 Chron 30:25)
In Esther’s time “many of the people of the land became Jews” (Esther 8:17, 9:27)
Even in NT times, many Jewish synagogues were attended by godly gentiles converted to Judaism (Acts 13:16, 26, 16:14, 17:17)
Many Jewish proselytes came to worship in Jerusalem (John 20:20, Acts 2:9-11)
Jesus quotes Isa 56:7, “My house shall be a house of prayer for all nations”, Mark 11:17.
Further, biological Israelites could opt out of the covenant and be cut-off (Ex 30:33, 38, 31:14, Lev 7:20, 21, 25, 27).

